# Creating an R dataframe column using row values and aggregate value

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, tapply

I have some fish catch data. Each row contains a species name, a catch value (cpue), and some other unrelated identifying fields (year, location, depth, etc). This code will produce a dataset with the correct structure:

```
# a sample dataset
set.seed(1337)
fish = rbind(
  data.frame(
    spp = "Flounder",
    cpue = rnorm(5, 5, 2)
  ),
  data.frame(
    spp = "Bass",
    cpue = rnorm(5, 15, 1)
  ),
  data.frame(
    spp = "Cod",
    cpue = rnorm(5, 2, 4)
  )
)
```

I'm trying to create a normalized cpue column `cpue_norm`. To do this, I apply the following function to each cpue value:

```
cpue_norm = (cpue - cpue_mean)/cpue_std
```

Where `cpue_mean` and `cpue_std` are, respectively, the mean and standard deviation of `cpue`. The caveat is that I need to do this *by each species* i.e. when I calculate the `cpue_norm` for a particular row, I need to calculate the `cpue_mean` and `cpue_std` using `cpue` from **only** that species.

The trouble is that all of the species are in the same dataset. So for each row, I need to calculate the mean and standard deviation of cpue *for that species* and then use those values to calculate cpue_norm.

I've been able to make some headway with tapply:

```
calc_cpue_norm = function(l) {
  return((l - mean(l))/sd(l))
}

tapply(fish$cpue, fish$spp, calc_cpue_norm)
```

but I end up with lists when I need to be adding these values to the dataframe rows instead.

Anyone who knows R better than me have some wisdom to share?

Comment: Question closed as duplicated. Use this `fish <-
  fish %>%
  dplyr::group_by(spp) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cpue_norm = (cpue - mean(cpue, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(cpue, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: data.table: `as.data.table(fish)[, cpue_norm := (cpue - mean(cpue))/sd(cpue), by = .(spp)]`; base R: `ave(fish$cpue, fish$spp, FUN = function(z) (z-mean(z))/sd(z))`; and you have dplyr from above.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!